# Difference in deploying Java web application and web service on Azure Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, azure, tomcat, azure-webapps

I am having a trouble with deploying on Azure's Tomcat servlet container. I connect to created web-app space with FTP copying the `war` file to the correct folder.

**myWebApp**

I have successfully deployed a Spring MVC simple web application on Azure. The URL pattern is below and the both work as expected:

- `http://myWebApp.azurewebsites.net/myWebApp` Deployed on Azure Tomcat
- `http://localhost:8080/myWebApp` Deployed on local Tomcat

The key file is `web.xml` below:

```
<web-app ... xsd schemas ... >

    <display-name>myWebApp</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>... not important ...</context-param> 
    <listener>... not important ...</listener>
</web-app>
```

---

**myWebService**

Well, the problem comes when I want to deploy a simple web service the same way and see its content.

I have decided to use `jersey` library. Here is the only sample class:

```
@Path("Sample")  
public class Sample {
    @GET  
    @Path("/")  
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)  
    public String Method() {
        return "<tag>" + 123 + "</tag>";  
    }
}
```

After `clean install` and running on local Tomcat server on URL `http://localhost:8080/myWebService/Sample`, it correctly gives me the XML `<tag>123</tag>"`.

I hopefully deployed on Azure the same way like the previous **myWebApp** and tried to run on the URL `http://myWebService.azurewebsites.net/myWebService`. It gaves me the `404` error instead, saying that the requested resource is not available.

Here is the `web.xml` for sure:

```
<web-app ... xsd schemas ... >
    <display-name>myWebService</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>nch.webservices</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

---

What am I missing and I do wrong? I have noticed the difference between both `web.xml` files in `url-pattern` that:

- **myWebApp** uses `/`
- **myWebService** uses `/*`

When I use `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` on **myWebService**, then it either doesn't work on localhost. Thanks for help. Feel free to ask for more info if needed (wanted to make the question as short as possible).

Comment: This is a problem about path.1.Please show me the line "<Context docBase="myWebApp " path="/" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:myWebApp "/></Host>" which can be found in your Azure tomcat/conf/server.xml.2.Let me know your project Context root which can be found in your IDE.Right Click your project---Properties---Web Project Settings.3.How many folders are in your Azure tomcat/webapps directory?Are they ROOT and myWebApp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description & codes, I tried to reproduce your issue of the `myWebService` successfully. The issue `404` of accessing `http://myWebService.azurewebsites.net/myWebService` of `myWebService` was caused by the `url-pattern` not match the `Method` url of class `Sample`, please see the explainations below.

1. In the class `Sample`, the class annotation `@Path("Sample")` and the method annotation `@Path("/")` for method `Method` means that the accessable url for the method `Method` of the class `Sample` in `myWebService` project is `http://myWebService.azurewebsites.net/myWebService/Sample/`.
2. The `url-pattern` value `/` means only match the url `http://myWebService.azurewebsites.net/myWebService/`.

There are two solutions for your case.

1. Recommended. Using the wildcard `/*` instead of `/` for `url-pattern` and access the url `http://myWebService.azurewebsites.net/myWebService/Sample/`.  And suggestion that change the class annotation `@Path("Sample")` to `@Path("/Sample")` for reading and understanding.
2. Only change the class annotation `@Path("Sample")` to `@Path("")` or `@Path("/")` if not change `url-pattern`, but any path annotations for other classes will not be matched.

Comment: You made my day! I appreciate your attempt to reproduce it for me and thanks for your hints.. the both of solution works like a charm! Thanks a lot ;))